# Get value from json format object in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have a json format data back from calling a WebApi I would like to get access to the value of exception.

This is the content of `response.data` :

> Key: UserEmailAdress
>   value:null

How I can get the value of UserEmailAdress?

[image]

This is my method that returns the object I need to have some logic here depend on the value I am getting back in UserEmailAdress.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Search(UserInfo userInfo)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    object userObject = null;

    if (userInfo.LastName != null && userInfo.Zip != null && userInfo.Ssn != null)
    {

        string accessKey = CreateAccountKey(userInfo.LastName, userInfo.Zip, userInfo.Ssn);

        var response = await client.GetAsync(string.Format("{0}{1}/{2}", baseUrl, "/verifyuser", accessKey));

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            userObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result) as object;
        }
    }

    var respone = new
    {
        success = userObject != null,
        data = userObject
    };
    return Json(respone);
}
```

Comment: What does inner exception say ?

Comment: The response seems to have been successful and therefore there is no exception, in other words, it is null. What's the problem?

Comment: @Versatile added one more picture to my question.

Comment: @ManoDestra it is not always null, the exception is name of the field I am getting back from the webAPI, so it may return with some messages that I need to show. so I like to get access to the Value of exception, remoterefnumber,... I  can get access by jquery in my view but don't know how get the values in controller.

Comment: Then grab the exception that occurs and put it in the response in whatever form you require.

Comment: @ManoDestra I changes the question to pick another field to prevent misunderstanding.

Comment: How I can get the access to the value something like. response.data[2]. ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after playing around in the debugger, I found that `DeserializeObject` returns a  `Dictionary<string, object>`, so you can cast your deserialized object to that, and it works

```
var json = "{\"exception\":null,\"remoteRefNumber\":\"testremref\",\"userEmailAddress\":\"t‌​est@yahoo.com\"}";

Dictionary<string, object> userObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(json) as Dictionary<string, object>;
```

Comment: I am not sure what should I use for (json) as I have response.data and data in object as well.

Comment: @Alma well, what does  `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` look like?

Comment: "{\"exception\":null,\"remoteRefNumber\":\"testremref\",\"userEmailAddress\":\"test@yahoo.com\"}"

Comment: @Alma okay, and specifically which of those values to you need?

Comment: I need exception and null, remoteRefNumber that is key and its value, pretty much I need all of the keys and their values.

Comment: but when I have this the userverify object is null ,    var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    var userverify = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<VerifyUser>(json);

Comment: so instead of the class Key value I need to have a class with Exception and RemoteRefNumber and UserEmailAddress

Comment: @Alma i just totally changed my answer